# How to select result of 2 multi conditional columns

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

im trying to display a result based on 2 multi-conditional columns.
I have 3 columns,One being a client, one of them is Product and one of them is Class. There are multiple products that each have multiple classes. I only want to display the results of specific classes of different products. Eg : Product X has a class of 1,2,3 I only want to see the results of Product X of classes 1 & 2. Product Y has a class of 1,2,3 but i only want to see results of Product Y for 1&3. Im new to SQL,is this something that i would need to use multiple case statements for or will that not work because that only works the result of a column? Or multiple select statements? Thanks in advance for any help! :)

```
Client   Product     Class
 Jeff      X           1
 Bill      X           2
 Sam       X           3
 Wendy     Y           1
 Jane      Y           1
 Tom       Y           2
 Dave      Y           3
------------Result----------
Jeff       X           1
Bill       X           2
Wendy      Y           1
Jane       Y           1
Dave       Y           3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the results you are looking for by using a where clause with an OR statement.

```
WHERE (product=‘x’ AND class IN (1,2)) OR (product=‘y’ AND class IN (1,3))
```

Comment: Just an improvement to this answer, here it is an sqlfiddle that do this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e85181/1